# Mobile browser doesn't find css files

Tags: html, css

I'm building my first website and the structure is as follows:
a folder named website containing two subfolders named html and css. The html folder contains one file named home.htm and the css folder contains two files named general_style.css and home_style.css.

In home.htm i have put the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>My title</title> 
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" 
content="width=device-width, 
initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="../css/general_style.css" 
type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="../css/home_style.css" 
type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet"   

href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head> 
<body>  
<!-- code goes here -->
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine in Firefox on my desktop, but not in Chrome on my smartphone. On the smartphone only the html is shown and the icons from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css.

All the code from my own css files is not shown neither are the icons from https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js.

Can somebody help me out here?

PS: both html and css files are validated with no errors or warnings.

Comment: try clearing cache and restart your browser.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say why it is not working. But I can tell you that if you're planning on building websites and testing them on various devices, you might want to run a local web server. This way, all your files can be hosted in your computer and you can access your site from any device connected to your network, using the local IP address of the computer that hosts the files. (ex: 192.168.0.x/home.html would show you your site if you open it in your mobile browser, without having to manually transfer any files.)

This is also the preferred method since it is closer to how users will access your website in the future.

You might want to look up "how to run a local web server" to find some guide that suits you. There are many methods and software tools to choose from.

If you are on a Mac, here's a quick and easy way to run one:

1. Go to **/Library/Web Server/Documents** and paste a folder with all your code and assets. Name it something simple, with no spaces
2. Open the terminal and type **sudo apachectl start**. It will prompt you for your password. Type it and press enter. (it might seem like its not typing because it wont show you anything, but it is working.)
3. Open your browser and type **localhost** in the address bar. You should see some big serif bold letters that read "**It works!**".
4. You're all set! Now just visit **localhost/folder-name/home.html** and it should show you your site! (hint: you might want to rename your home.html to index.html. If you do so, you will be able to visit localhost/folder-name/ and the server will automatically load index.html

Remember that if you are going to access this from your mobile phone or any other device, you *must* be connected to the same network. Also, entering **localhost** will not work. From other devices you must provide the local IP address of the computer running the server. Something like this: 192.168.0.5/folder-name/home.html/. You can find the computer's local IP in your Network Preferences.

(This works because macOS comes with the Apache webserver software preinstalled, and has set the /Library/Web Server/Documents/ folder to be hosted by apache. What we do in the terminal is just turn apache on. You can turn it off by typing "sudo apachectl stop" in the terminal).

Comment: To add to this, Visual Studio Code has a [live-server plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) that allows you to host your web development site straight away. 
And the JetBrains editors have a built-in [web server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/php-built-in-web-server.html#ws_html_preview_output_built_in_browser).

Comment: I found out what was wrong. It was An issue with the URL. Firefox used file:/// while Chrome used content://. After changing IT it found the css files, but the layout is scewed up. It's kinda the same as in browser desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run your code on mobile browser?

Since it works on your computer Firefox browser smoothly but it wont work on mobile phone, this might be because you dont have the CSS files on your mobile device and have them on your desktop.  I think that is a issue.

Comment: Yes i do. I just copied the files to my phone and put them in exactly the same folder structure.